# extract time from timedelta

Tags: python, timedelta

I have a list:

```
[Timedelta('0 days 00:02:39.210526'),
 Timedelta('0 days 00:03:29.033333'),
 Timedelta('0 days 00:03:36.333333'),
 Timedelta('0 days 00:01:04'),
 Timedelta('0 days 00:04:05.571428'),
 Timedelta('0 days 00:04:00.500000'),
 Timedelta('0 days 00:03:54.583333')]
```

How can I extract only the time from this list?

Comment: I ... err ... you don't.  Time deltas are _not_ times.  They are _lengths of time_.  If you have a datetime, and you add/subtract a time delta, you get a new datetime, but the timedelta's themselves do not represent any specific point in time. You're asking "what time is three minutes?"  That doesn't make any sense without a reference, IE "three minutes from _when_?"

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to extract the time component *as a string*, removing all reference to "days" even if your `Timedelta` is greater than 1 day.

One way is to convert your `Timedelta` to a normalised `datetime` and then use the `time` attribute.

Below is also a trivial way to convert your `Timedelta` objects to strings.

Note this uses a 3rd party library `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [pd.Timedelta('0 days 00:02:39.210526'),
       pd.Timedelta('1 days 00:03:29.033333'),
       pd.Timedelta('5 days 00:03:36.333333'),
       pd.Timedelta('2 days 00:01:04'),
       pd.Timedelta('10 days 00:04:05.571428'),
       pd.Timedelta('8 days 00:04:00.500000'),
       pd.Timedelta('1 days 00:03:54.583333')]

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': lst})

df['B'] = (pd.Timestamp('now').normalize() + df['A']).dt.time
df['C'] = df['A'].astype(str)

print(df)

                        A                B                           C
0  0 days 00:02:39.210526  00:02:39.210526   0 days 00:02:39.210526000
1  1 days 00:03:29.033333  00:03:29.033333   1 days 00:03:29.033333000
2  5 days 00:03:36.333333  00:03:36.333333   5 days 00:03:36.333333000
3         2 days 00:01:04         00:01:04   2 days 00:01:04.000000000
4 10 days 00:04:05.571428  00:04:05.571428  10 days 00:04:05.571428000
5  8 days 00:04:00.500000  00:04:00.500000   8 days 00:04:00.500000000
6  1 days 00:03:54.583333  00:03:54.583333   1 days 00:03:54.583333000

print(df.dtypes)

A    timedelta64[ns]
B             object
C             object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the `datetime` module and that your list of `Timedeltas` is called `my_timedelta_list`, you could do the following to obtain the time differences in seconds:

```
my_times = []
for t in my_timedelta_list:
    my_times.append(t.total_seconds())
```

Then your `my_times` variable would have the time differences in seconds.

You can then convert the seconds to whatever time unit and format you want.